# Getting different answers with MATLAB and Python norm functions

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am getting two vastly different answers with regards to simple matrix norms when comparing the MATLAB and Python functions.

Let

```
R =

    0.9940    0.0773   -0.0773
   -0.0713    0.9945    0.0769
    0.0828   -0.0709    0.9940
```

Then in MATLAB:

```
>> norm(R)

ans =

     1
```

But in Python

```
from scipy.linalg import norm
import numpy as np

print norm(R),np.linalg.norm(R)

1.73205080757 1.73205080757
```

where

```
print scipy.__version__,np.__version__
0.14.0 1.9.0
```

How did I manage to so comprehensively screw that up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is returning the Frobenius norm.  You can do this in MATLAB with:

```
>> norm(R,'fro')
ans =
          1.73203140271763
```

By default, [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) gives the 2-norm (`norm(R,2)`).

Answer (score 7):

Either do this in MATLAB:

```
>> norm(R,'fro')
```

or this in Python:

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(R,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Matlab default for matrix norm is the 2-norm while scipy and numpy's default to the Frobenius norm for matrices. Specifying the norm explicitly should fix it for you